# Aligning elements inside stacked DIVs

Tags: html, css, alignment, structure

### Description of Problem:

I'm attempting to arrange the kittens in a star-like pattern with 3 DIV "rows." I would like for the first top row's kitten to be centered on the page (easy enough); the second (or '#middle') row to have their cats left-aligned and right-aligned, respectively; and the third ('#bottom') row to have its cats aligned similar to the second row, but slightly indented on both sides. Again, like a star.

I know the `float` property essentially makes the element(s) absolutely positioned, which collapses the bottom two rows' height, so that's probably not the right answer. But I've also tried `text-align` and futzing with margins.  My brain is fried.  What am I doing wrong?

### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k97CG/1/

### HTML Structure:

```
<div id="top">
  <div id="container1" class="containers">
    <div id="cat1">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/125/125" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="middle">
  <div id="container2" class="containers">
    <div id="cat2">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/125/125" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container3" class="containers">
    <div id="cat3">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/125/125" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
  <div id="container4" class="containers">
    <div id="cat4">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/125/125" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container5" class="containers">
    <div id="cat5">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/125/125" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS Structure:

```
.containers {
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
}
#top, #middle, #bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#container1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#container2 {
    float: left;    
}
#container3 {
    float: right;
}
#container4 {
    float: left;
}
#container5 {
    float: right;
}
```

---

Comment: Sigh... it's because I didn't define the "row" heights. Son of a...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just place them all in one div, then position them with CSS?

```
    <div>
        <img id="img01" src="img1">
        <img id="img02" src="img1">
        <img id="img03" src="img1">
        <img id="img04" src="img1">
        <img id="img05" src="img1">
    </div>
```

then

```
 div {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }
 div img {
    position:absolute;
 }

 #img01  { 
    top:x;
    left:y;
 } etc
```

As a rule, you shouldn't rely on HTML for visually styling content unless you have no other option. That's what CSS is for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the one you are looking for:

```
#top, #middle, #bottom {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    clear:both;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k97CG/2/)</kbd>